# Play simple beep with python without external library

Tags: python, playback, noise

Using only the modules that come with a standard python 2.6 installation, would it be possible to play a simple beeping noise?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13941/python-sound-bell

Comment: So I would have to go through the default os's speech to text program?  Also I am not using a mac all of the time. This would have to be cross platform.

Comment: @a sandwhich: Read the *answers* at the link, not the question.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you're on a Unix terminal, you can print "\a" to get a terminal bell:

```
>>> def beep():
...     print "\a"
>>> beep()
```

Of course, that will print a newline too… So `sys.stdout.write("\a")` might be better. But you get the idea.

Comment: you can also do `print "\a",` and it won't do newlineb

Comment: also works on macs however it uses your speaker so if say you have headphones in it will use your headphones or if it is muted it won't work.

Comment: Works fine for me on Windows 7, even through headphones.

Comment: what is the main difference between `print "\a"` and `sys.stdout.write("\a")`?

Comment: @Mathias711 that… is actually a more complex question than it seems. In this case, `print "\a"` is basically the same as `sys.stdout.write("\a\n")`; `sys.stdout.write("\a")` won't always work because `sys.stdout` is usually line buffered (so you won't "see" the write until a newline is written). For more, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263672/python-the-difference-between-sys-stdout-write-and-print

Answer (score 20):

On windows:

```
import winsound         # for sound  
import time             # for sleep

winsound.Beep(440, 250) # frequency, duration
time.sleep(0.25)        # in seconds (0.25 is 250ms)

winsound.Beep(600, 250)
time.sleep(0.25)
```

34.4. winsound — Sound-playing interface for Windows:

http://docs.python.org/2.6/search.html?q=sound&check_keywords=yes&area=default

See also:
Clear screen and beep for various platforms. (Python recipe) 
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577588-clear-screen-and-beep-for-various-platforms/

Answer (score 2):

On Android with QPython this is how it goes:

```
import androidhelper
droid=androidhelper.Android()
droid.generateDtmfTones('0',100)
```

This will place a beep of a certain frequency for certain time.

Comment: It's `generateDtmfTones()`. You're missing an `f`. https://kylelk.github.io/html-examples/androidhelper.html