# Sound alarm when code finishes

Tags: python, alarm, audio

I am in a situation where my code takes extremely long to run and I don't want to be staring at it all the time but want to know when it is done.

How can I make the (Python) code sort of sound an "alarm" when it is done? I was contemplating making it play a .wav file when it reaches the end of the code...

Is this even a feasible idea? 
If so, how could I do it?

Comment: what operating system are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04, and the code is in python.

Comment: I'd be interested to know how to do this in Windows, as well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307305/play-a-sound-with-python

Comment: Is there something that works for OS X? I can't seem to find the winsound module.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Play audio with Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/260738/play-audio-with-python) Ubuntu bash: http://askubuntu.com/questions/277215/make-a-sound-once-process-is-complete

Comment: @CharlieParker in terminal on Mac I just use `say` and type something like `say your program has finished`

Answer (score 378, accepted):

### On Windows

```
import winsound
duration = 1000  # milliseconds
freq = 440  # Hz
winsound.Beep(freq, duration)
```

Where freq is the frequency in Hz and the duration is in milliseconds.

### On Linux and Mac

```
import os
duration = 1  # seconds
freq = 440  # Hz
os.system('play -nq -t alsa synth {} sine {}'.format(duration, freq))
```

In order to use this example, you must install `sox`.

On Debian / Ubuntu / Linux Mint, run this in your terminal:

```
sudo apt install sox
```

On Mac, run this in your terminal (using macports):

```
sudo port install sox
```

### Speech on Mac

```
import os
os.system('say "your program has finished"')
```

### Speech on Linux

```
import os
os.system('spd-say "your program has finished"')
```

You need to install the `speech-dispatcher` package in Ubuntu (or the corresponding package on other distributions):

```
sudo apt install speech-dispatcher
```

Comment: right You have to download it, I'll give you the link, let me find it...I just posted another one for macs that will actually speak to you, so it can tell you when it's done

Comment: thanks! do you happen to know if linux has one that will speak to you too?

Comment: mine says that say is not found, even though i've installed sox and play works. but i've found an alternative.

import os
os.system('espeak "your program has finished"')

Comment: winsound isn't found. Is it not available for OS X?

Comment: @CharlieParker, if you look at the full answer, the first option is only for windows users. The others state how to on other environments, which includes OSX

Comment: absolutely love the OSX one :D

Comment: Linux Mint 17.3 Rosa - this works! os.system('play --no-show-progress --null --channels 1 synth %s sine %f' % ( a, b)

Comment: I think it's worth adding in this post, for Windows and winsound you need not worry about Beep frequency and duration. Just using winsound.MessageBeep() will be enough.

Comment: TIL I can make my computer talk using the os package!  So awesome!!

Comment: I love this lol

Answer (score 50):

```
print('\007')
```

Plays the bell sound on Linux. Plays the [error sound on Windows 10](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qlUFWSiOXpM).

Comment: This doesn't appear to work through ipython/Jupyter

Comment: does not work on VS code nor Jupyter notebooks on win10

Comment: Does not work on my computer (Linux Mint 20) !

Answer (score 43):

This one seems to work on both Windows and Linux* ([from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4467240/play-simple-beep-with-python-without-external-library)):

```py
def beep():
    print("\a")

beep()
```

In Windows, can put at the end:

```py
import winsound
winsound.Beep(500, 1000)
```

where `500` is the frequency in Herz and `1000` is the duration in miliseconds

To work on Linux, you may need to do the following (from QO's comment):

- In a terminal, run `cd /etc/modprobe.d` then `gksudo gedit blacklist.conf` to edit `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` as root.
- Comment out the line that says `blacklist pcspkr`, then reboot.
- Also check that the terminal preferences has the `Terminal Bell` option checked.

Comment: thanks! just to add, may need to turn on the terminal bell sound in ubuntu gnome for it to work.

Comment: @mtigger Could you please explain how to do that, so that we can update the answer... (or you can update)

Comment: in a terminal, type  'cd /etc/modprobe.d' then 'gksudo gedit blacklist.conf'. uncomment the line that says 'blacklist pcspkr', then reboot. check also that the terminal preferences has the 'Terminal Bell' checked.

Comment: how to check "that the terminal preferences has the 'Terminal Bell' checked" in ubuntu 13?

Comment: "\a" worked for me on the Ubuntu subsystem for Windows, thanks!!

Comment: does not work on VS code nor Jupyter notebooks on win10

Comment: Does not work on my computer (Linux Mint 20) !

Answer (score 24):

I'm assuming you want the standard system bell, and don't want to concern yourself with frequencies and durations etc., you just want the standard windows bell.

```
import winsound
winsound.MessageBeep()
```

Answer (score 17):

ubuntu speech dispatcher can be used:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['speech-dispatcher'])        #start speech dispatcher
subprocess.call(['spd-say', '"your process has finished"'])
```

Comment: but, starting to play when process finished.

Comment: that's what the intended behaviour is, you want the sound when the process finishes

Comment: you can add `-w` argument to wait while spd-say finishes the phrase

Answer (score 14):

[Kuchi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16573255/168594) didn't work for me on OS X Yosemite (10.10.1). I did find the `afplay` command ([here](https://superuser.com/a/598800/42310)), which you can just call from Python. This works regardless of whether the Terminal audible bell is enabled and without a third-party library.

```
import os
os.system('afplay /System/Library/Sounds/Sosumi.aiff')
```

Answer (score 11):

Why use python at all?  You might forget to remove it and check it into a repository.  Just run your python command with && and another command to run to do the alerting.

```bash
python myscript.py && 
    notify-send 'Alert' 'Your task is complete' && 
    paplay /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/suspend-error.oga
```

or drop a function into your .bashrc. I use apython here but you could override 'python'

```bash
function apython() {
    /usr/bin/python $*
    notify-send 'Alert' "python $* is complete"
    paplay /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/suspend-error.oga
}
```

Comment: great, it works. also with `os.system("paplay sound-alarm.oga")`

Answer (score 6):

See: [Python Sound ("Bell")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13941/python-sound-bell)
This helped me when i wanted to do the same.
All credits go to [gbc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1667/gbc)

### Quote:

Have you tried :

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write('\a')
sys.stdout.flush()
```

That works for me here on Mac OS 10.5

Actually, I think your original attempt works also with a little modification:

```
print('\a')
```

(You just need the single quotes around the character sequence).

Answer (score 4):

It can be done by code as follows:

```
import time
time.sleep(10)   #Set the time
for x in range(60):  
    time.sleep(1)
    print('\a')
```

Answer (score 3):

A bit more to your question.

I used [gTTS](http://pip%20install%20gTTS) package to generate audio from text and then play that audio using [Playsound](http://pip%20install%20playsound) when I was learning webscraping and created a coursera downloader(only free courses).

```
text2speech = gTTS("Your course " + course_name +
                                " is downloaded to " + downloads + ". Check it fast.")
text2speech.save("temp.mp3")
winsound.Beep(2500, 1000)
playsound("temp.mp3")
```

Answer (score 3):

I created a python module that reminds developers on Telegram application after code execution. It might be more helpful than making alarm sound.

Pypi link:
https://pypi.org/project/devreminder/

Github link:
https://github.com/cagataygulten/devreminder

Example:

```
In [1]>>
    from devreminder import DevReminder
    import time

In [2]>>
    remind = DevReminder(1932126911,False,0)

In [3]>>
    remind.me("Example")
    time.sleep(6)
```

Output:

[image: An example of reminder message]

Please follow README file for more information.

Answer (score 3):

On macOS there's a dead simple way to do it.

```
python file.py && say done
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(['D:\greensoft\TTPlayer\TTPlayer.exe', "E:\stridevampaclip.mp3"])
```

Comment: You should add some comments or other explanation for this code to explain how it works and why it answers the question.