# Is it possible to add a noise alert to webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium, pycharm, webdriver

I have searched through the forums and have come upon nothing covering this question. I am looking to add a noise alert in selenium, python webdriver when I find a certain X path.
(Like a buzzer or a beep)
I have only found info pertaining to pop up alerts when I search for alerts. What I would like to do is have a noise alert when I find a certain link

```py
Driver.get(“google.com”)
Driver.find_element_by_text(“search button”).click()
```

I want to add an alert when this is clicked for example

Comment: This may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573051/sound-alarm-when-code-finishes

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (assuming you are on Windows):

```
import winsound
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

duration = 1000  # milliseconds
freq = 440  # Hz

Driver.get(“google.com”)
element = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
if element.is_displayed():
    winsound.Beep(freq, duration)
    element.send_keys("Python")
    element.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    print("found")
else:
    print("not found")
```

Comment: if element.is_displayed():
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_displayed'

Comment: I was assuming your original element was correct, it was not, assuming you are trying to click the search button.  I updated the code.  BTW you may want to add code to enter some text in the search box first before clicking the button

Comment: `import winsound
duration = 1000  # milliseconds
freq = 440  # Hz


driver.get("https://www.google.ca/?gws_rd=ssl")
time.sleep(5)
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/form/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/center/input[2]").click()   `           it works up until i add if element is displayed then it gives that error

Comment: still getting that error, im not sure whats wrong

Comment: Ok, I think I know what the issue is.  When google.com loads that button is hidden for some reason, but the search box is not. I changed the code above for testing purposes, to look for the search box instead of the search button.  This is just for testing purposes, you will want to add error handling etc to your code

Comment: Okay so just to get it clear, we are loading google and looking for the letter ‘q’. If it is not found we will get a print message saying it’s not there.. but if it is there we will get windows alert noise etc.. have you tried this code yet? I will try tomorrow in the morning . Appreciate you helping me

Comment: @Sauls_bHlls. Correct, you are looking for the element 'q', which is the search text box element.  if its there you get the print message (and hopefully alert).  I have tested the print function, but not the winsound function,  since I work on a Mac and that is Windows specific.  Hopefully it works ok for you. If you want a Mac version you can click on that initial link I commented on your post, I think there is one there