# Microsoft VS Code jupyter notebooks

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, notify

Is there a way for VS code to notify the user when the cell execution has been completed in `.ipynb` files?

Answer (score 2):

There are probably many more options you can do, here I list two of them.

1. Set an alarm at the end of the cell, for this, you can check the following links:

- [alarm1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17323336/automatically-play-sound-in-ipython-notebook)
- [alarm2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573051/sound-alarm-when-code-finishes)

2. You can send emails to you if you are not close to your computer and want to get notified. for this please check following links too:

- [email1](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/email.examples.html)
- [email2](https://realpython.com/python-send-email/)