# How can i make a sound in python?

Tags: python, audio

I tried to make a sound with the winsound libry and my system doesnt recognize it...
Can I write a code in python that makes a sound without installing a new libraries?

I searched some solutions but all I found doesnt work. 
I need a library that included in the python package.

```
import winsound
winsound.Beep(300,2000)
```

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Play simple beep with python without external library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4467240/play-simple-beep-with-python-without-external-library)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sound generation / synthesis with python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9770073/sound-generation-synthesis-with-python)

Comment: If you just want to play a sound, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27978895/11109346) might work for you.

Answer (score 4):

You can try cross-platform way to do this is to print **'\a'**. This will send the ASCII Bell character to stdout, and will hopefully generate a beep (a for 'alert').

Even Windows has its own Beep API, which allows you to send beeps of arbitrary length and pitch. Note that this is a Windows-only solution, so you should probably prefer print '\a' unless you really care about Hertz and milliseconds.

The Beep API is accessed through the winsound module:
[Link to Python Winsound Library](http://docs.python.org/library/winsound.html)

Answer (score 3):

First: What is your OS? According to the documentation [winsound](https://docs.python.org/3/library/winsound.html) "access to the basic sound-playing machinery provided by Windows platforms". So **winsound** only works
on **Windows**, so if you're a **LINUX** or **UNIX** you have to find another way.

Seconds: What to you mean by "make a sound" if you just want a "beep" you can use **beep** and call it with **os.system** from os module (or subprocess) like this:

```
import os

os.system('play --no-show-progress --null --channels 1 synth %s sine
%f' %( 0.1, 400))
```

You have to install beep (it's an "advanced" pc-speaker beeper), the installation depend on your system Mac/OSX, Linux(Ubuntu/Debian, Fedora, Archlinux), BSD?
on Ubuntu/Debian: sudo apt-get install beep

**Update #2**
@shahar Well according to the [doc](http://docs.python.org/3.5/library/winsound.html#winsound.Beep) you did the right thing.

You can catch error that python raise to you to figure it out what's wrong

```
try:
    import winsound
    winsound.Beep(400, 1000)
except RuntimeError:
    print("The system is not able to beep the speaker")
except ImportError:
    print("Can't import winsound module")
```

The code above work on python2.7 and python3 but in case, what's your python version?
I used python3.5.3 on windows and the code work like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

You can play back an mp3...
but this will require a library

a good example is here:-
[Playing mp3 song on python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20021457/playing-mp3-song-on-python)

```
from pygame import mixer # Load the required library

mixer.init()
mixer.music.load('e:/LOCAL/Betrayer/Metalik Klinik1-Anak Sekolah.mp3')
mixer.music.play()
```